# Does catch(...) always make sense?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Does it always make sense to catch every exception "just to make sure"? For example:

```
try
{
    Socket_Listen();

    if(Return_Value == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw SOCKET_LISTEN_ERROR;
    }

    __LOG__ << "Listening..." << endl;
}

catch(EError_ID)
{
    __LOG__;
    Get_Last_Error_As_String( __FUNCTION__ );
}

catch(...)
{
    __LOG__ << "WARNING: An unknown error occurred." << endl;
}
```

I'm throwing an error I have defined myself (`SOCKET_LISTEN_ERROR`), which is part of a larger enum that contains multiple error IDs. Is it possible that there is some other exception thrown here, besides the one I have thrown? For the sake of completeness, here is `Socket_Listen()`:

```
void CTCPServer::Socket_Listen()
{
    Return_Value = listen( Socket,
                           2 ); 
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to know that some exceptions _may happen_ and catch only them. If some other exception occurs, this could possibly mean there's a flaw in your code. Also, by catching with `catch(...)`, you're getting rid of the information about the exception, which is no good.

Comment: `For the sake of completeness` Are you kidding? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems that you mixed up all you know: exceptions, errno-like variables, return codes. Choose one error handling strategy and stick with it. Sometimes people [disable exceptions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113479/are-there-any-real-world-cases-for-c-without-exceptions) (it is common e.g. in gamedev).

Comment: The only real good use for catching all exceptions is to log something really/really/really unexpected happened at a specific point. You then **re-throw** the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary, it *rarely* makes sense to catch every exception. When you exit a `catch` block (without rethrowing), you're telling the surrounding code that the exception has been resolved and the program can continue running normally.

When you catch all exceptions without any knowledge of what they are, you can't possibly make the claim that everything is normal. It's better to *ignore* unexpected exceptions than to swallow them up. Let the caller worry about them (possibly by letting them go to the caller's caller, and so on).

You ask whether there are any other exceptions that could be thrown from that code. I don't know, and neither do you, so it certainly makes no sense to catch them. If testing reveals other kinds of exceptions, and if that location is the right place to handle them, then add code to handle them there. Until you know what to expect, though, remove the catch-all exception handler.

Comment: Thank you. Your expanation was very easy to understand.